# Property bag - Index using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, client-object-model

How can we check if the property bag is indexed and searchable?

And also how is the index value for **'vti_indexedpropertykeys'** encoded?

**I am trying to update the property bag's index using CSOM C# in .NET**.So wanted to know how to verify it and know in what format the values are stored?

I found a AddIndexedPropertyBagKey property but do not know what value to set it with and what does it do.

```
Web web = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.AllProperties);
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Description);
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Title);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var allProperties = web.AllProperties;
web.AddIndexedPropertyBagKey = ??
```

Comment: do you want a CSOM C# solution ?

Comment: yeah..thats right @GautamSheth

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198134/what-is-the-best-practice-to-create-property-in-propertybag-indexed-for-searc

Comment: please check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2013/10/12/ftc-to-cam-setting-indexed-property-bag-keys-using-csom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the PnP Core Nuget package in your project.

It is a wrapper over the Native CSOM C# and provides a lot of extensions.

Using that, you can easily set the property bag value as well as mark it as indexed.

Use the below code:

```
Web web = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
clientContext.Web.SetPropertyBagValue("key", "value");
clientContext.Web.AddIndexedPropertyBagKey("key");
```

To get the `IndexedProperty` bag you can fetch the list of indexed property bags. If your property bag is marked as indexed, it will be available in the list:

```
var indexedPropertyBags = clientContext.Web.GetIndexedPropertyBagKeys();
```

Nuget Package - [SharePointPnPCoreOnline](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/)